# How to Bind a Button for holding in KivyMD

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I`m binding a MDButton in KivyMD and I dont know how to bind(set) a Button`s command for holding it to react

can someone helps me?

I tried on_key_down command

i want to when i held a list item, or button
that button`s command works for me

Comment: You could bind a method to the `on_press` event of the `Button`. In that method you could use `Clock.schedule_once()` to schedule whatever you want for the hold function. You would schedule that using the required duration of a hold. Then in a method that you bind to the `on_release` event, you would cancel the scheduled clock event.